# Mouse pointer hiding in Kotlin's Jetpack Compose for Desktop

Tags: kotlin, user-interface, raspberry-pi, android-jetpack-compose

I need to create a GUI running on Raspberry PI 4B connected to a touch screen. When the app is running I would like the mouse pointer to be hidden since it's not needed on such type of screens.

I've read I can add a nocursor option as follows `xserver-command = X -nocursor` in the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. Now I am not able to verify that since my RPI hasn't been shipped yet. Also I wouldn't like to hide the pointer completely on the OS but rather only when the app is running.

I couldn't find anything interesting either in the documentation of Compose or source classes itself that's why I am asking here.

Answer (score 1):

To hide the mouse pointer only when your app is running on Raspberry Pi 4B with a touch screen, you can use the following code snippet in your GUI application:

```kotlin
import java.awt.Cursor
import java.awt.Point
import java.awt.Toolkit
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box

fun main() {
   Window(){
      Box(modifier = Modifier
          .pointerHoverIcon(
              PointerIcon(createEmptyCursor())
          )
      )
   }
}

private fun createEmptyCursor(): Cursor {
    return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(
        BufferedImage(10, 10, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB),
        Point(0, 0),
        "Empty Cursor"
    )
}
```

In my case, this solution worked perfectly. I am using Jetpack Compose for Desktop, and the code snippet I provided utilizes the core Java AWT classes. By adding the necessary imports (import java.awt.*) at the beginning of your file, you can integrate this solution seamlessly into your application.